# problema con la conexión sql server

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

Hola tengo este error SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client y esta es mi clase conexión la cual llamo en otra clase $conn= new class_db; y $r= sqlsrv_query($conn->getConecta(), $query); alguien podria decirme en que me estoy equivocando funcionaba bien solo de repente me lanzo ese error

```
 class class_db
 {

        private $conn;
  function __construct() {
    try
 {
   $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server = tcp:*************.database.windows.net,1433; Database = 
  **************", "****.******", "********");
   $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  }

  catch(Exception $e)
  {
  die(print_r($e));
  }
  }

  function __destruct() {
    try {
        $this->conn = null; //Closes connection
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print("Error connecting to SQL Server.");
  die(print_r($e));
    }
  }

        public function getConecta(){
            return $this->conn;
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola seguro has cambiado de versión de php y también tienes que cambiar de dll y ODBC driver 17 for sql server.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567

```
$serverName = "localhost";  
try{  
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=MIBD", "sa", "123456");  
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
echo 'conexion exitosa';
}  catch(Exception $e)  {   
die( print_r( $e->getMessage() ) );   
}
```